# How to make a centered bubble chart in python/matplot lib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to make a centered bubble chart in matplotlib / python similar to this.

[image]

Some people have called it a "bottom aligned bubble chart", So far, I've basically found a way to do a concentric circle scatter plot.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = [ 50000.,10478.2, 4733.4,3185.3,2484.7,2310.9]
x = [1]*len(s)
y = [0]*len(s);
plt.scatter(x,y,s=s);
plt.show()
```

Any ideas on how to line up the bottom edges of these concentric cirlces?

Comment: It's a scatter plot, with the size set for each point, and each point plotted at one radius higher than the common bottom point.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not sure why this question was put on hold... Check my answer here: https://gist.github.com/wmvanvliet/73b821746e401f9ba935

Answer (score 4):

I would interact with matplotlib artists directly. I would also set the radius -- and therefore center -- of each circle the square root of the populations.

This is because, for a circle, `A ~ r^2`, so you'll heavily distort the size differences if `r ~ population`.

So all that said:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

seaborn.set(style='white')

populations = numpy.sqrt([50000., 10478.2, 4733.4, 3185.3, 2484.7, 2310.9])
cp = seaborn.color_palette('Blues_r', n_colors=len(populations))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for n, p in enumerate(populations):
    circle = plt.Circle((1, p), radius=p, facecolor=cp[n])
    ax.add_artist(circle)

ax.set_xlim(-max(populations), max(populations))
ax.set_ylim(0, 2 * max(populations))
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

Gives me this:

[image]